# Via Paypal API what call can I use to transfer from my paypal balance to my bank account

Tags: api, paypal, transfer, bank

I would like to automate my paypal balance to my bank.
Tired of having to go every weeks and click on the transfer to my bank.

What API call can I use to transfer my paypal balance back to my linked bank account ?

Answer (score 1):

There is not an API that you can use to transfer the money to your bank.  But you can set up Auto Sweep on your account.  Once you enable this feature on your PayPal account, PayPal will send what ever funds are in your PayPal account to your bank account on a daily basis.  This would mean that you would not need to go into your account every time and do this manually, it would be done automatically.

In order to enable this on your account, you would first need to contact PayPal customer service, and request this feature enabled on your account.  Once your account has this enabled on it, you will then need to go into your account and turn this on.

Comment: yes but Auto Sweep everyday is a nightmare for accounting.
I need an auto sweep every weeks.

How can I file a request for a call to be created ??

Would there be some other ways to do it? like curling the page, ... ???

Comment: Unfortunately there is not an API that you can use to do this.  As for submitting a feature request, this can be done at www.paypal.com/mts but if you submit a feature request, there is not type ETA as to when this will be implemented or if it will be implemented.  This would be something passed on to the development team, and it would be up to them if they choose to implement this or not.  As for curling the page, I have not heard of anyone doing this specifically.  I have seen programs that merchants use that do a page scrape and get the details of transactions/history but that’s about it.

Comment: I did try to look at how to file a request for a new call but the system seems to be very not helpful, ..... send us an email, ... so I did but there are no tracking if it has been considered, ... ???

Comment: No there is no tracking if it has been considered.

Comment: Are there beeen any progress made on this ?

Comment: @PP_MTS_Chad can you update us on whether there is now direct access via the APIs to allow us to facilitate transfers from someone's PayPal account to their linked bank account? I can't seem to find a way to do this, still.